# Problems mapping UUID in JPA/hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, uuid

According to the documentation, hibernate 3.6 should have support for the java.util.UUID type. But when I map it like:

```
@Id protected UUID uuid;
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [test-applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:529) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:495) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:629) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:338) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:911) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308) ~[spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -2
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:78) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlTemporaryTableCreateString(Table.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.prepareTemporaryTables(PersistentClass.java:765) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:270) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

I know questions with stack traces are not very popular but this is a very hibernate-specific problem and I have been unable to find anything on google :)

Thanks

Comment: What rdbms are you using and which jdbc driver version are you using?

Comment: MySQL 5.1.47 and mysql-connector 5.1.13

Comment: actually, questions _without_ stacktraces are unpopular.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

UUID was a basic type added in 3.6. However, by default it translates to a JDBC Binary type which appears to cause issues for mysql. You can override this behavior by explicitly specifying uuid-char as the type.

Comment: Ok, what if I want to story it in binary(16)?

Comment: If that is the case then you will want to do something akin to partenon's answer. It sounds as though from your comment to his answer that for whatever reason 16 bits are not enough. It is probably how the mapping in mysql's jdbc driver is working. I'll need to do more research to be able to provide specifics. If you want to play around with it to see what's happening try upping it to binary(32) and seeing what gets put in the db.

Answer (score 52):

Extending Mike Lively's answer with a code sample & referring to Oracle too.

I had this problem with the OracleDialect (Oracle10gDialect). Adding an annotation @Type to the UUID field fixed it for me.

```
@Id
@Type(type="uuid-char")
private UUID id;
```

Note: also used a TwoWayStringBridge on this field, using the @FieldBridge annotation.

Note: type="uuid-binary" did not work; got the same, unknown type error.

Comment: Is there any global property to set this as default mapping for all java.util.UUID to uuid-char so I don't have to type this annotation for every entity using UUID? (I also want to avoid hibernate specific annotation in my code and leave it all javax.persistance.

Comment: Yes! See jpkrohling's answer below. Just customize your database dialect and register the column type in its constructor.

Comment: Inspired by this answer, I got spring JPA working with Oracle DB (In Kotlin): ```@Column(name = "uuid")  @Type(type="uuid-char") var uuid: UUID? = null.```  When using it, ```val x = UUID.fromString("00a023b3-1357-3070-a661-72a09f8ccdb2")``` to convert from str to uuid. On Oracle db: ```ALTER TABLE ADD UUID RAW(16) default SYS_GUID()  NOT NULL```.

Comment: Thanks @Emily!! Glad this helped inspire you.

Comment: This was a life saver. Thank you

Comment: @Barett how do you do this with hibernate 6 and an UUID array?

Comment: That would be a new question.

Answer (score 10):

Using Hibernate 4 and MySQL 5.5 with an InnoDB table, I was able to store a `UUID` column as `BINARY(16)` as-is (no configuration or custom type required). I am not using this as the entity ID and am creating the value manually using `UUID.randomUUID()`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class PostModel implements Serializable
{
    ...
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID uuid;
    ...
}

> desc post;
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default             |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+
| ...            |               |      |     |                     |
| uuid           | binary(16)    | YES  | UNI | NULL                |
| ...            |               |      |     |                     |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------------------+
```

Comment: How do you get values back as UUID?

Comment: Hibernate does the mapping automatically. Does your code match what I added to my answer?

Comment: This is the best answer for Hibernate 4 and above !

Comment: Still the perfect answer in 2020

Answer (score 9):

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -2
```

This means that UUID is being mapped as BINARY[1] by Hibernate, but none MySQL Dialects maps BINARY to a MySQL data type. Take a look at the Dialect hierarchy for MySQL:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5Dialect.java

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQL5InnoDBDialect.java

Compare them with this one (search for the BINARY mapping):
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/HSQLDialect.java

This *may* be a bug in Hibernate, as I do see the BINARY data type available in the MySQL documentation, but you may want to do some search in Hibernate's JIRA to see if there's any reason why this is not mapped.

If you are willing to test, you can just subclass MySQL5InnoDBDialect (if you are using InnoDB), and use this to the constructor:

```
registerColumnType( Types.BINARY, "binary" );
```

So, this is the reason why the String is working, but java.util.UUID is not.

1 - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.BINARY

Comment: I did that and got this instead: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'uuid' at row 1

Comment: I would read the MySQL documentation about this, and I would try to come up with a way to store this UUID binary data into a MySQL column with data type as binary using JDBC only. If you are able to do that using pure JDBC, then Hibernate should also be able to. In this case, open a issue in Hibernate JIRA with as much details as possible (bonus points if you attach test cases). I'm quite sure the fine folks at Hibernate will accept it and will be glad to get your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the type `UUID`, because you'd need a custom type to handle it.

Use `String`. See [this post](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=3). It is one way of implementing it.

Another way is to use the UUID generator built in hibernate. You'd need `@GeneratedValue` with a generator named `hibernate-uuid`

Comment: Using String is not very efficient for querying and storage. Also, hibernate 3.6 is supposed to have support for mapping of UUID types? Or do I need to have it in combination with @generatedvalue for it to work?

Comment: And how will you store it in the database, if not as string?

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me trying to connect to a MS SQL server.

Comment: Using UUID and not String has one key advantage, you will never need to worry about upper or lower case id's. In my app ids were coming from different sources so the case could differ sometimes which caused some trouble when comparing them.

Comment: I'm using String, and the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41651681 happens to me, so it is not a solution.

Comment: Link in answer is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Google search led me to this post when I was looking for UUID mapping with JDBC so I'll post my experience if you don't mind.

On my project I'm switching between H2 and MySql using H2 in unit-testing. H2 natively supports UUID type. But mysql java connector doesn't. So my only option is to convert `BINARY(16)` to `UUID` in client code which I don't like.

As result I patched official mysql java connector to treat UUID as BINARY(16). I know it's kinda hacky but works for me.

If you want to try it I posted it on github: http://goo.gl/NIhNi

Comment: Your link is giving 404.

Comment: @BugsBuggy Yeah, sorry about that. I thought nobody uses JPA in 2020 so I deleted the repo. I recommend using `Jdbi`.