# How to store uuid in binary form using hibernate JPA 2

Tags: java, hibernate, binary, jpa-2.0, uuid

I have a question about string uuid in database in binary form through hibernate persistence (JPA2). I'm using now this code:

```
private UUID id;

@Id
@Type(type="uuid-char")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(length = 32, unique = true, nullable = false)
public final UUID getId() {
    return id;
}
```

This work fine, but I must store it in binary form. Don't ask me why, but I must.

Answer (score 7):

The type for binary UUID is `uuid-binary`. You must have Hibernate 3.6 for this to work.

For many more details and pitfalls, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346898/problems-mapping-uuid-in-jpa-hibernate).