# Storing UUID as string in mysql using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, uuid

I came across a blog of using UUID with Hibernate and MySql. Now the problem is, whenever I take a look at the database the ID's will be non-readable format (binary-16). How can I store UUID as a readable format like `7feb24af-fc38-44de-bc38-04defc3804fe` instead of `¡7ôáßEN¹º}ÅÑs`

I was using this code

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue( generator = "uuid2" )
@GenericGenerator( name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2" )
@Column( name = "id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)" )
private UUID id;
```

And the result is **¡7ôáßEN¹º}ÅÑs**. But I want it as readable UUID so I used the following code which didn't help me

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue( generator = "uuid2" )
@GenericGenerator( name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2" )
@Column( name = "id", columnDefinition = "CHAR(32)" )
private UUID id;
```

How to save the UUID as a string instead of binary(16) without changing the java type UUID

Comment: Think about this.. UUID in binary(16) is better for performance.

Comment: You got result ¡7ôáßEN¹º}ÅÑs from console or any GUI tool?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394039/modeling-uuid-in-hibernate-entity-against-mysql

Comment: Why save it in an inefficient format? Just use `BIN_TO_UUID(id)` when you need to actually look at the table.

Comment: @dkb I copy pasted that value from mysql table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes I agree to that, but is there a way for just representing UUID in string in tables and use it as UUID object in java ?

Comment: `BIN_TO_UUID(id)` will only work in MySQL 8.0 @RealSkeptic

Comment: "yes I agree to that, but is there a way for just representing UUID in string in tables and use it as UUID object in java ?" if you use MySQL 5.7+ you can use a generated column to generate a human readable UUID from the binary id column -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html .. or use a basic view if you don't have MySQL 5.7+

Answer (score 53, accepted):

just use 
`@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="uuid-char")`

There is three levels of data types:
- Java types
- Hibernate's types
- Database Specific types.

Hibernate data type presentation is a bridge between Java data type and Database types to be independent from database.

You can check this [mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic). 
As you can find there `java.util.UUID` can be mapped to diferent types (binary or char/varchar). `uuid-binary` is key to hibernate's UUIDBinaryType, you get this type by default and it will be mapped to `BINARY` of your database.

If you want to get CHAR type under your UUID, you should explain to hibernate that you want his `UUIDCharType`. To do that you use `uuid-char` key and as you can check in JavaDoc of @Type annotation: `Defines a Hibernate type mapping.`. So, you use annotation to explain hibernate which bridge it should use.

Comment: Could you explain your answer a little?

Comment: @ficuscr I've added explanation

Answer (score 9):

The @Type annotation is deprecated and does not even exist in the last version of Spring Boot.

You need to use now @JdbcTypeCode

The correct way to do that is the following

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)
```

Comment: this should be on top. Works on Spring Boot 3

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in my last project (**spring-boot:2.5.3** + **mariaDB**).
So I added the following annotation `@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")` to fix it.

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;
/** imports */

@Entity()
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "uuid", columnDefinition = "char(36)")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
    private UUID uuid;

   /** ... */
}
```

The purpose of the hibernate annotation `@Type` is to define the type of data stored in database and it's compatible with the previous line `@Column(name = "uuid", columnDefinition = "char(36)")`

> *While googling it, I noticed that mariaDB & MySQL have the same issue.*

You can [see here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.hibernate.annotations.Type) more examples in different use cases for `org.hibernate.annotations.Type`

Answer (score 1):

i'm using this annotations:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2r")
@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "varchar(36)")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
private UUID uuid;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).