# Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc

I'm trying to write tests using in-memory DB. 
I wrote an sql to clean and store data to DB. But I have an exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "e7485042-b46b-11e9-986a-b74e614de0b0"; SQL statement:
insert into users (user_id, name, created_on, modified_on) values ('e7485042-b46b-11e9-986a-b74e614de0b0', 'Ann', null, null) -- ('e7485042-b46b-11e9-986a-b74e614de0b0', 'Ann', NULL, NULL) [90004-199]
```

My sql:

```
insert into users (user_id, name, created_on, modified_on) values ('e7485042-b46b-11e9-986a-b74e614de0b0', 'Ann', null, null);

insert into product(product_id, name, created_on, modified_on) VALUES ('f3a775de-b46b-11e9-95e4-af440b6044e6', 'product1', '2019-08-01 17:51:51.000000', '2019-08-01 17:51:51.000000');

insert into products_users(user_id, product_id) VALUES ('e7485042-b46b-11e9-986a-b74e614de0b0', 'f3a775de-b46b-11e9-95e4-af440b6044e6');
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: Try removing the hyphens from the UUID string values.

Comment: What is the datatype of `user_id`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, uuid

Comment: @GordThompson, then I get MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: e7485042b46b11e9986ab74e614de0b0

Comment: Removing the hyphens means you'll end up with a String that does not respect the UUID format conventions. Reconversion from a binary format into a valid UUID thus results in a type mismatch.

Comment: @kateswerg did you eventually sort it out?

Comment: @EnricoGiurin I did sort it out. Please read my answer thoroughly to understand what exactly is causing it and how to solve it.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to my `application.properties` file

Comment: How is this even possible? ddl-auto=none will prevent tables from being created in your h2 database and thus no entry can be inserted.... Furthermore: if you're working with spring boot and have h2 on your classpath (scope test), h2 is automatically configured for you making your configuration redundant (except for the console enabled = true)

Comment: this is fully unrelated to the subject of the question

Answer (score 12):

Using **spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MYSQL** fixed it for me.

Or adding an annotation @Type to the UUID field should fix the issue:

```
@Id
@Type(type="uuid-char")
private UUID user_id;
```

Comment: Can you explain what this do?

Comment: My answer, actually explains what causes this and does not provide a copy paste answer. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

The actual cause of this problem is the mapping between your object and the generated `create table` statement by hibernate (`ddl-auto:create`) used to create your h2 database schema.

If you enable the output of the those `ddl` statements using:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

you will most likely see that your `UUID` class has been mapped to a **binary** column in your database.

```
Hibernate: 
    create table <your_table> (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        ...,
        <your_object> binary(255),
        ...
        primary key (id)
    )
```

This means that your uuid-string is mapped onto a binary column and thus contains illegal characters. You need a  `varchar(<uuid-length>)` column to store a uuid. There are several solution strategies, one of them is defining a type, see this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346898/problems-mapping-uuid-in-jpa-hibernate). You can read on `binary` columns on the official [MySQL reference site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-varbinary.html).

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by having a foreign key constraint on a table, that is incorrect (ie one table has UUID as the key, and the other has varchar as the key).

example:

Imagine you have

```
user.id => UUID
some_table.user_id => varchar(255)
```

You will get this error if you have the following constraint on `some_table`

```
 constraint fk_user_id foreign key (user_id) references user,
```